# Use of same admob publisher id (Ad unit id) in more than one android application?

Tags: android, admob

Is there any problem in using same ad unit for more than one android app ?
(Am taking about admob ads) I mean, this violation to their terms or policy ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For reporting sake, use different ad unit for each application. This helps you know how each application is performing in regards to eCPMs, requests and clicks. It will help you understand the market, adjust or improve your apps as needed.

It's not against the policy if that's what you want.  ([Check this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/gNZ6xD0IXw8/x6axuJEmXK8J))