# adding the same admob unit id on multiple android apps

Tags: android, admob

I created an AdMob account and built some Android apps and I want to know if 
is there any problem if I added the same AdMob unit ID on multiple Android apps?

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047067/use-of-same-admob-publisher-id-ad-unit-id-in-more-than-one-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there would not be any problem if you add single unit-id of admob to multiple apps.

But its better to keep unique unit-id of admob which helps to know how a particular app. is performing in requests and clicks. Which will help you to understand android market, you can also adjust and/or improve your app.